# How to avoid the hidden classes using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, classname, ng-hide

I am trying to refer to a class using classname with selenium but the same class got a hidden tag with exactly same name and all other values except ng-show=false

AS below:

```
ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked ng-hide" ng-show="false" <br>
ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"
```

How can I refer to the second tag?
I didn't try @tabIndex as sometimes, the hidden tags are more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find by the missing class `ng-hide`. Find element witch has the classes
`nav nav-pills nav-stacked` but not `ng-hide`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked:not(.ng-hide) > div"));
```

Or by not having `ng-show="false"`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked:not([ng-show='false']) > div"));
```

Comment: Sorry for not framing the question correctly earlier. But I am trying to refer the Div Class tag with in the ul class that I mentioned above. This div class tag doesnt have ng-hide/show mentioned. Hope I am clear here.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @megan assuming the `<div>` tag is the direct child just add `> div` at the end, this will give you direct child with `<div>` tag. I added it to my answer as well.

Comment: yes but its giving all the div tags with in. Can I limit it to the very first div tag. Thanks

Comment: Got it working by giving the classname along with the div. Thanks for your help! @Guy